# Sum query not working properly properly sql and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Why this query instead of displaying the sum of points for each user, it display the sum of all together

I have written an `SQL` query that displays the sum of all point for all users, whereas I would like it to: *display the sum of points for each user.*

The table that I have written contains the following:

```
id  |  Score
1   |   20
2   |   30
2   |   50
1   |   10
```

Total table :

```
id | points

1  | 30

1  | 40
```

What I want is to add the score for `user(1) = 30` and `user(2) = 80`

```
Id: 1 = 30 = Fail
Id: 2 = 80 = Pass
```

The query I have written :

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sg.score) as sum, SUM(a.total) as suma FROM points as sg, totalpoints as a
          WHERE a.id = 1 GROUP BY sg.id";
```

And related `PHP` code is as follows:

```
<?php
  foreach($rowsum as $rowsm): 
    if( ' '. htmlentities($rowsm['sum']) . '' > 50  )
      echo 'Pass';
    else if( ' '. htmlentities($rowsm['sum']) . '' >= 40  )
      echo 'Failed';

    echo ' ' . htmlentities($rowsm['sum'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '<br>';

  endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should look forward using the `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT 
   SUM(score) AS sum 
FROM 
   points 
 GROUP BY 
   id 
 ORDER BY 
   id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the users ID:

```
SELECT SUM(score) as sum FROM points GROUP BY id ORDER BY id
```

You also have an incorrect WHERE clause

```
WHERE id=id
```

isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You've omitted the GROUP BY clause:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(score) as `sum` FROM points GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
```

Your WHERE clause wasn't needed.

Comment: Thank you :), and It is posible to first sum all the values and then do the sum for id

Comment: If you want the total sum included you can do it with a subselect:

Answer (score 0):

You need to do group by as below and it will give you the sum of scores for each user

```
SELECT SUM(score) as sum FROM points 
group by id 
ORDER BY id
```

If you need to find it for a specific user just add a where condition as

```
SELECT SUM(score) as sum FROM points 
where id = 1
```

The above will give the sum of scores for id = 1 and can change for other values as needed.

Comment: I updated my question, hope you can help is a diff query

Comment: In this case you need to use the first query and will return exactly what you want.

Comment: My problem is that total point, Im getting it from a different table

Comment: different table ? you may need to add the table and data in that case to your question.